# "Can only send requests to friends or users of this application"

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-requests

Using the code

```
FB.ui({
            method: 'apprequests',
            filters: 'app_non_users',
            message: $filter('i18n')('voices-invite-facebookMessage'),
            to: users // an array of uIDs
        }, function(data){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
```

I get the following dialog:

[image: Can only send requests to friends or users of this application]

From the documentation I fought I was able to invite friends to use my app, did I understand it wrong?

Thanks

Comment: are you sure the users on the array, you're passing, doesn't have the app already installed

Comment: I am :)
Meanwhile I remembered that having the app in sandbox mode would be the reason, but making it live didn't solve anything out. :(

Comment: One more thing this is a canvas app or an iframe app(app inside a facebook page)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that actually the people I was inviting weren't "my friends". The access token provided to fetch the friends and the one that the SDK logged in, and used to do the `FB.ui` request weren't the same. Sorry for your time...